# error syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Tags: python, node.js, windows, npm, environment-variables

Whenever I try to run any nodejs project I am getting an error showing that `error syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`. The same error is hitting for all the nodejs projects. The problem was arised after installing python and modifying the system environment variables with pythonpath. The error I am getting is:

```
verbose stack Error: firsttypescript@1.0.0 start: `tsc-watch --onSuccess "node ./dist/index.js" --onFailure echo`
verbose stack spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
verbose stack     at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
verbose pkgid firsttypescript@1.0.0
verbose cwd D:\trainingTasks\firstTypeScript
verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
verbose node v8.11.3
verbose npm  v5.6.0
error file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
error path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
error code ELIFECYCLE
error errno ENOENT
error syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
error firsttypescript@1.0.0 start: `tsc-watch --onSuccess "node ./dist/index.js" --onFailure echo`
error spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
error Failed at the firsttypescript@1.0.0 start script.
```

My system environment variable path is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;‪C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\abhishek.m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;%PYTHONPATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have ComSpec variable C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe.

And try to replace path value without \cmd.exe :
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;‪C:\Windows\System32;%SystemRoot%\sy...blah...